# Python Regex, Matching Whole Words with Spaces with date and time

Tags: python, xml

How would i match these specific lines from an XML file:

'< Foobar >example created 9/30/2014 11:00:010 AM < /Foobar > AZ9999This Is A Test - Please Help Backup-Full'

So far I currently match all strings

```
    #Regex for matching specific line
   found = re.match(r"^(?<=FooBar)+(\d+/\d+/\d+).$", text)
```

I am able to read the file just unable to extract these specific string from the file.

Comment: What does your code look like? Which part doesn't work? Have you tried a Python package that was made for parsing XML?

Comment: Why do you keep removing the formatting?

Comment: I apologize, i'm new to stackoverflow. unsure how to post a properly constructed question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve are your friends in this respect.  Please read and follow them; we depend on this background to keep StackOverflow running smoothly.  Note that your "Welcome" materials included specific reference to these pages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified what you need to find, I can't give you a tested code snippet.  Please check the various help pages and the regexp tutorials.  I can recommend

http://flockhart.virtualave.net/RBIF0100/regexp.html

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

I think that you may need something like this:

```
def isText(text):
    found = re.match(r"This is a test", text)
    if found:
        return True
    return False
```

which easily collapses to

```
return re.match(r"This is a test", text)
```

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the feedback.
This is what i would like to explicitly extract from the XML file

'< Foobar >example created 9/30/2014 11:00:010 AM < /Foobar > AZ9999This Is A Test - Please Help Backup-Full'

Comment: Fine -- so plug all of that into the search string.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Im stuck at spaces inbetween some of the words. also theres a date that o need to extract. This format  9/30/2014 11:00:010 AM

Comment: Then please *specify* what you need.  Follow the "mcve" link above.